# ¿Por que mi managerbean no borra entidades al mandar mi entidad?

Tags: java, jpa

Por alguna razón al intentar eliminar una entidad con

```
public void remove(Notification notification){
    try {
        em.merge(notification);
        em.remove(notification);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("No se pudo remover la notificación "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

me manda este error

```
Entity must be managed to call remove: 4, try merging the detached and try the remove again.
```

pero con al usar:

```
public void remove(Notification notification){
    try {


        em.merge(em.find(Notification.class, notification.getId()));
        em.remove(em.find(Notification.class, notification.getId()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("No se pudo remover la notificación "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Me gustaría saber por qué ocurre eso, pues tengo entendido que

```
(em.find(Notification.class, notification.getId())
```

debería devolver la misma entidad que le mando con

```
em.remove(notification);
```

Simplemente no le encuentro sentido. Espero me ayuden a comprender. por qué ocurre.

Comment: JSF no tiene nada que ver con esto. JSF en este escenario solo sirve para ejecutar la acción que indica el usuario en la interfaz web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método [`EntityManager#merge`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge-T-) devuelve una instancia asociada al contexto, no va a modificar la instancia que envías como parámetro. Para que tu código funcione, debería ser así:

```
Notification mergedNotification = em.merge(notificacion);
//luego de la línea anterior:
//notification sigue siendo el mismo objeto del parámetro sin modificaciones
//mergedNotification es una nueva instancia de la clase Notification
//que está asociada al contexto de JPA (nivel 1 de caché, para ser precisos)
//ahora lo puedes remover
em.remove(mergedNotification);
```

La ventaja de este método es que es útil cuando quieres hacer una eliminación de los objetos en cascada. Pero ojo, ten cuidado con el rendimiento de la aplicación en este caso. Considera que cuando usas `EntityManager#merge` debe registrar el objeto en la base de datos por `INSERT` o `UPDATE` y realizar otras operaciones adicionales (p.e. reflexión)  lo cual afecta el rendimiento de la aplicación, sobretodo si el objeto es muy pesado p.e. si tiene un campo blob que posee una imagen o un archivo. Si se trata de una sola entidad básicamente sin relaciones o si deseas realizar una operación masiva (conocidos mejor por su término en ingles *bulk operation*), lo mejor en términos de rendimiento sería usar el API Criteria con un código como sigue:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaDelete<Notification> query = cb.createCriteriaDelete(Notification.class);
Root<Notification> root = query.from(Notification.class);
query.where(cb.equal(root.get("id"), notification.getId()));

int result = entityManager.createQuery(query).executeUpdate();
```

También lo podrías lograr con JPQL pero el API Criteria tiene la ventaja de que puede recibir la clase como parámetro, lo cual facilita crear un método más genérico para generalizar el código de arriba, por ejemplo:

```
interface Entidad<T> {
    T getId();
    void setId(T id);
}

public class Notification implements Entidad<Integer> {
    /* definición de la clase */
    Integer id;
    //getter y setter..
}

class DaoGenerico {
    EntityManager em;
    public DaoGenerico(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }
    public <E extends Entidad<?>> void borraMedianteApiCriteria(Class<E> claseEntidad, E entidad) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaDelete<E> query = cb.createCriteriaDelete(claseEntidad);
        Root<E> root = query.from(claseEntidad);
        query.where(cb.equal(root.get("id"), entidad.getId());
        em.createQuery(query).executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

Comment: No es así, si la entidad no esta en el persistent context al utilizar .merge la entidad es agregada al persistent context y su estado es transferido a la misma entidad con el mismo identificador si es que fue cargado anteriormente, nada de esto se persiste a la base si no haces flush...

Comment: Eso esta en la especificación de JPA, aquí hay un articulo que lo resume http://spitballer.blogspot.com/2010/04/jpa-persisting-vs-merging-entites.html

Comment: @Carlos ahora que leo mejor tu comentario, no entiendo la parte que dices "no es así". Por el contrario de lo que planteas, lo que yo digo es que la entidad `Notification notification` del parámetro no está asociada al contexto, por ende al usar `merge` se asocia al contexto y devuelve esta entidad asociada, sea por `insert` o `update`. La del parámetro mantiene su estado tal cual. Lo del flush es otro cantar.

Comment: Me refiero a la parte que mencionas que trae el objeto de la base en este hilo de stackoverflow en ingles puedes ver mas detalles http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509086/what-is-the-difference-between-persist-and-merge-in-hibernate

Comment: @CarlosLucero oh ok, era parte de corregir esas palabras. No significa que la respuesta estaba mal per se. Corregido.

Comment: Ok, adicionalmente JPQL/HQL vs Criteria API exponen el mismo API la diferencia de rendimiento entre estos dos es unicamente que una consulta JPQL/HQL debe ser parseada en runtime a diferencia de Criteria API que expone el API en sus clases, pero en si a la final estas haciendo lo mismo, Criteria API es mucho mas flexible cuando realizas agregación, composición etc en las consultas. pero en este ejemplo realmente no estas mejorando el rendimiento y con NamedQuerys puedes obtener el mismo rendimiento que Criteria API, pero en mi caso solo uso para consultas genericas el resto solo Criteria API

Comment: @CarlosLucero mientras que el rendimiento es el mismo indistinto de Criteria API o JPQL, el esfuerzo de desarrollo con Criteria API es mucho menor al de estar escribiendo los queries para cada entidad ;) x ende es "mejor". El rendimiento no es el único factor que indica la calidad del software.

Comment: Eso no es rendimiento es productividad, esto segundo es subjetivo porque depende de otras variables concernientes al desarrollador y casos de uso concretos y no técnicos, continua mal tu respuesta sobre el funcionamiento de merge, adicionalmente la cache L1 es utilizada para almacenar información de las transacciones mientras que es en la cache L2 en la que se almacenan las entidades que se han cargado al persistent context como la que cargas al hacer merge este es otro error en tu ejemplo en concreto, en fin mi intención es dar información mas precisa dejando de lado polémicas q no caben aquí

Comment: @Carlos creo que solo intentas buscar problemas. La publicación la corregí, si no te gusta pues ni modo. Y el L2 es caché externo como ehcache o Hazelcast. Revisa bien antes de publicar.

Answer (score 0):

En hibernate las entidades pueden estar en cualquiera de estos [estados](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#d0e1014).

- New (transient): an entity is new if it has just been instantiated using the new operator, and it is not associated with a persistence context. It has no persistent representation in the database and no identifier value has been assigned.
- Managed (persistent): a managed entity instance is an instance with a persistent identity that is currently associated with a persistence context.
- Detached: the entity instance is an instance with a persistent identity that is no longer associated with a persistence context, usually because the persistence context was closed or the instance was evicted from the context.
- Removed: a removed entity instance is an instance with a persistent identity, associated with a persistence context, but scheduled for removal from the database.

Hibernate solo puede trabajar con entidades Managed para poder manipular su estado y transferir esas acciones la base mediante SQL, caso contrario no te permitira, por lo tanto una entidad Detached que esta fuera del persistent context no se puede persistir o modificar en la base, para ello debes regresar tu entidad de vuelta al persisten context y convertir tu entidad Detached a Managed.

En tu caso la entidad 'libro' que llega como parámetro el método a sido desasociada del *persistence context* por lo tanto no esta siendo gestionada (Detached) por el, esa es la razón por la cual no te permite eliminarla.

Al hacer

```
em.find(Notification.class, notification.getId())
```

estas realizando una nueva consulta a la base de datos obteniendo una nueva entidad, en este caso si esta dentro del *persistence context* y por esa razón te permite eliminarla.

al hacer

```
em.merge(libro); // libro pasa al persistence context y se convierte en un managed entity
em.remove(libro);
```

estas agregando la entidad desasociada (Detached) 'libro' al *persistence* *context* mediante el metodo *.merge()* por lo tanto esta entidad desasociada (Detached) ahora pasa a ser gestionada (Managed), por esa razón ahora puedes eliminar.

Ahora en tu siguiente ejemplo, este fragmento de código.

```
em.merge(em.find(Notification.class, notification.getId()));
em.remove(em.find(Notification.class, notification.getId()));
```

puedes simplificarlo como

```
Notificacion notificacion = em.find(Notification.class, notification.getId());
em.remove(notificacion);
```

Sin embargo esto a SQL se traduce a lo siguiente.

```
SELECT * FROM notificacion WHERE id = :id
DELETE FROM notificacion WHERE id = :id
```

El primer *select* es necesario en hibernate ya que así obtienes la entidad gestionada (Managed) para poder eliminarla luego con em.remove, pero si solo necesitas el ID para poder eliminar una entidad en SQL entonces técnicamente el primer *select* es un desperdicio.

Otra manera de eliminar una entidad desasociada es así.

```
Libro entity = getEntityManager().getReference(Libro.class, libro.getId());
getEntityManager().remove(entity);
```

En este caso *getReference* crea una entidad proxy y no carga el estado (los datos) del libro de la base de datos. (solo puedes llamar a los métodos set de este objeto proxy).

Esto es mucho mejor ya que al no cargar los datos de la base esto únicamente hace el *delete* y no el primer *select*.

```
DELETE FROM libro WHERE id = :id
```